# Plot daily time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series of 20 obs (date, price). I'm trying to plot the series through ggplot with the code: `ggplot(timeseries, aes(x=date, y=price)) + geom_line(col="indianred", size= 1)`

I want to ask: how can I include every single day in the x-axis? I had only three days in the x-axis.

[image]

Comment: See the function `scale_x_continuous()`

Comment: welcome to SO. Veeeeery useful to use `?`, for information on the function. In this case, as suggested by @Dave2e, use `?scale_x_continuous`

Comment: what should I include inside scale_x_continuous in order to include every single day in the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date breaks are 1 day, you can use `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day")` as below to include every day. (you can also try strings like `"2 days"` or `"1 week"` as needed.)

```
lol <-tibble(date=c(Sys.Date()-7,Sys.Date()-6,Sys.Date()-5,Sys.Date()-4,Sys.Date()-3,Sys.Date()-2,Sys.Date()-1),price=c(1,23,21,9,6,2,32)) 

ggplot(lol, aes(x=date, y=price)) + geom_line(col="indianred", size= 1) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day")
```